# Exception "Access is denied" when trying to get process handle with "process.handle"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a `Handle` of a process using [`Process.Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.handle?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Handle) but i can't seem make anything work.

I have tried running as admin. I also tried to get a handle of all processes one by one. And this is the only account on this pc.

```
var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process pr in allProcesses)
{
    if(pr.ProcessName == "chrome")
    {
        //i've also tried to get the handle of explorer, this application etc..
        Console.WriteLine(pr.ProcessName);
        Console.WriteLine(pr.Handle); //this line fails.
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of Exception is thrown?  If it's an InvalidOperationException, it might be  that your process doesn't have the necessary permissions to access the Process Handle.

Comment: Quote from the MSDN article: "Only processes started through a call to Start set the Handle property of the corresponding Process instances".  Chrome is extra tricky because it by itself creates extra processes that don't have a distinctive name.  Don't do it.